# matanalysis topology continuum hypothesis for close sets

Tags: analysis

that is, we need to show that if the set is uncountable, then it is closed. My proof is that we will throw out isolated points from our closed set E onto a number set, get the set E '- the set of limit points of the set E. It turns out that our set E is the union of the perfect set E' with the set of isolated points, that is, it contains a set with a power of continuum, which means that the original set has a power not less than the continuum, on the other hand, our set is a subset of the whole number line that has a power of continuum. then its power is not greater than the continuum. then by the cantor-bershtein theorem its power is continuum. the only thing I don’t understand is how to prove that the set of limit points of our uncountable closed set will be a perfect set

Comment: "if the set is uncountable, then it is closed" I don't think that's what you meant to write.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit garbled, but seems to boil down to:

> Why is the set $E'$ of limit points of an uncountable closed set $E$ a perfect set?

The answer is, **it isn't**. For example, consider the set $$E=\{1-{1\over n+1}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup[17, 42]$$ (I consider $0\in\mathbb{N}$). Then $E'=\{1\}\cup[17,42]$, which is not perfect. But in this case $E''$ is perfect.

... But that doesn't hold in general either: consider for example the set $$F=\{1\}\cup\{1-{1\over n+1}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{{1\over n+2}-{1\over k}\cdot({1\over n+1}-{1\over n+2}): n,k\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup[17,42].$$ Here we have $$F'=\{1\}\cup\{1-{1\over n+1}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup[17,42]$\mbox{ and } F''=\{1\}\cup[17,42].$$ Here we need to go to $F'''$ to get the "perfect core" of $F$.

In general, if you're going to prove that every uncountable closed set has size continuum using [Cantor-Bendixson derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics)), you'll need to talk about *infinite iterations* of them.

---

There are other ways to prove the desired result. For example, if $E$ is uncountable and closed, let $\mathcal{U}$ be the set of open intervals with rational endpoints which have countable intersection with $E$. Let $U=\bigcup\mathcal{U}$ and let $C=\mathbb{R}\setminus U$ (I'm working in $\mathbb{R}$ for simplicity). Now show that $C$ is nonempty, closed, contained in $E$, and has no isolated points.

Here are a couple hints towards that last line:

- To show that $C\subseteq E$, use the fact that $E$ is closed. Can $C$ have any elements "far away" from every point in $E$?
- To show that $C$ is nonempty, note that $U$ is the union of countably many - since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable - sets, each of which has only countable intersection with $E$, so $U\cap E$ is countable. *(This is why we looked at rational open intervals!)*